# Scrolling background flicker in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, flicker

I am using the background scrolling tutorial on xnadevelopment.com (modified to suit my requirement) to create a vertical scrolling loop for a game on windows phone 7.1. It seems like the background is flickering whenever the next image is drawn. Though I am using a single image for the loop, the flickering occurs even if multiple images are used. I have posted a youtube video showing the flicker that occurs at the top of the screen.

http://youtu.be/Ajdiw2zILq0 
Below is the code used to create the loop:

**Background class:**

```
    private List<string> _road;
    private VericalBackgroundLoop _roadLoop;
    private readonly Vector2 _roadSpeed = new Vector2(0, 300);

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager contentManager)
    {
        _road = new List<string>
                         {
                             "Test\\Road_Bgnd",
                             "Test\\Road_Bgnd"
                         };

        _roadLoop = new VericalBackgroundLoop();
        _roadLoop.Initialize(_road, contentManager, Vector2.Zero, true);
    } 

    public void Update(TimeSpan elapsedTime)
    {
        _roadLoop.Update(_roadSpeed, elapsedTime);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        _roadLoop.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
```

**Background loop class:**

```
    private List<Sprite> _sprites;
    private bool _isLoopDirectionTopToBottom;
    private Vector2 _loopDirection;

    public void Initialize(List<string> spriteNames, ContentManager contentManager, Vector2 loopStartPosition, bool isLoopDirectionTopToBottom)
    {
        _sprites = new List<Sprite>();
        _isLoopDirectionTopToBottom = isLoopDirectionTopToBottom;

        _loopDirection = new Vector2(0, -1);

        // Build the sprite object's list
        foreach (string spriteName in spriteNames)
        {
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite.LoadContent(contentManager, spriteName);

            _sprites.Add(sprite);
        }

        if (_isLoopDirectionTopToBottom)
        {
            // Set the initial position for the sprite objects
            foreach (Sprite currentSprite in _sprites)
            {
                if (currentSprite == _sprites.First())
                {
                    currentSprite.Position = loopStartPosition;
                }
                else
                {
                    Sprite prevSprite = GetSpriteAtIndex(_sprites.IndexOf(currentSprite) - 1);
                    currentSprite.Position = new Vector2(0, prevSprite.Position.Y - prevSprite.Size.Height);
                }
            }
        }
     }

    public void Update(Vector2 loopSpeed, TimeSpan elapsedTime)
    {
        if (_isLoopDirectionTopToBottom)
        {
            foreach (Sprite currentSprite in _sprites)
            {
                if (currentSprite == _sprites.First())
                {
                    Sprite lastSprite = _sprites.Last();
                    if (currentSprite.Position.Y > (currentSprite.Size.Height))
                    {
                        currentSprite.Position.Y = lastSprite.Position.Y - lastSprite.Size.Height;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Sprite prevSprite = GetSpriteAtIndex(_sprites.IndexOf(currentSprite) - 1);
                    if (currentSprite.Position.Y > (currentSprite.Size.Height))
                    {
                        currentSprite.Position.Y = prevSprite.Position.Y - prevSprite.Size.Height;
                    }
                }

                // Update the sprite X position with the speed and time
                currentSprite.Position -= _loopDirection * loopSpeed * (float)elapsedTime.TotalSeconds;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (Sprite sprite in _sprites)
        {
            sprite.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }

    private Sprite GetSpriteAtIndex(int index)
    {
        return _sprites[index];
    }
```

I need help in figuring out why the flicker is occurring and why motion seems to be jerky and not smooth (it is a bit better on the device, but jerky nevertheless). IsFixedTimeStep is set to true in the game.cs class. Thank you.

**EDIT :** Seems like the flicker is not occuring if 3 or more images are used. This could be due to the first image not being placed back into the start position quickly enough. But am still trying to figure out whey the animation is still so jerky :(

Comment: I would use milliseconds, not seconds in time based movement. Otherwise you loose a lot of precision, because usually a frame takes less than a second.

Comment: To use milliseconds, I believe the speed has to modified? Any idea on how much should the speed be updated by?

Comment: If you divide the time by 1000 just divide the speed by 1000

Comment: Thank you both. The scrolling does seem a little smoother with milliseconds. The biggest difference (smoother) seems to be happening when IsFixedTimeStep is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be the first to report seeing flickers or stutters. Lots of posts on the App Hub forums about that. (glad you're finding luck using my tutorials/samples by the way!)

Here's an example of someone reporting what you're seeing -> http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/30500.aspx

And here's the best answer I've seen to date from one of the XNA Framework developers ->
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/9934/53561.aspx#53561

Basically you've stumbled onto "a" solution, but as Shawn's post points out there's a variety of ways to fix the problem, it just depends on what's right for your game.